# How to detect mouse click on GUITexture in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, click, touch

I am trying to add controls through mouse in place of keyboard in the game.
I added 4 movement keys and 1 fire button through the GUI texture in unity.
In the game there is already a player controller which controls the player through keyboard strokes

I didnt get, how to make the player move if the direction button (GUITexture) is clicked

Button Script

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RightButton : MonoBehaviour {

```
public Texture2D bgTexture;
public Texture2D airBarTexture;
public int iconWidth = 32;
public Vector2 airOffset = new Vector2(10, 10);


void start(){
    }

void OnGUI(){
    int percent = 100;

    DrawMeter (airOffset.x, airOffset.y, airBarTexture, bgTexture, percent);
}

void DrawMeter(float x, float y, Texture2D texture, Texture2D background, float percent){
    var bgW = background.width;
    var bgH = background.height;

    GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (x, y, bgW, bgH), background);

    var nW = ((bgW - iconWidth) * percent) + iconWidth;

    GUI.BeginGroup (new Rect (x, y, nW, bgH));
    GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (0, 0, bgW, bgH), texture);
    GUI.EndGroup ();


}
```

}

I am unable to add the GUI Button in place of GUI.DrawTexture, its giving invalid argument error
and so i am unable to add how to check the button is clicked or not

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUITexture is part of the legacy GUI system.  An example of how to get this to work as a button is [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/428642/guitexture-button.html).

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RightButton : MonoBehaviour {

    public Texture bgTexture;
    public Texture airBarTexture;
    public int iconWidth = 32;
    public Vector2 airOffset = new Vector2(10, 10);


    void start(){
    }

    void OnGUI(){
        int percent = 100;

        DrawMeter (airOffset.x, airOffset.y, airBarTexture, bgTexture, percent);
    }

    void DrawMeter(float x, float y, Texture texture, Texture background, float percent){
        var bgW = background.width;
        var bgH = background.height;

        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (x, y, bgW, bgH), background)){
            // Handle button click event here
        }

        var nW = ((bgW - iconWidth) * percent) + iconWidth;

        GUI.BeginGroup (new Rect (x, y, nW, bgH));
        GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (0, 0, bgW, bgH), texture);
        GUI.EndGroup ();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unable to change my code in GUI Button its giving error

Comment: If the error is because of the last argument, with the background texture parameter, redefine the background type to Texture instead of Texture2D and see if that works.  For example:

`public Texture2D bgTexture;`  
`public Texture2D airBarTexture;`  
`public int iconWidth = 32;`  
`public Vector2 airOffset = new Vector2(10, 10);`  
`void start(){....`

(Code formatting doesn't seem to work in comments)

Comment: I ran out of time messing with the code formatting.

Change any reference to "Texture2D" to "Texture"

Comment: Thanks it worked, but how could i make it to work for when ever the mouse is pressed and not have to keep clicking again and again

Comment: and i wanted the event in the button to be inherited from player controller which is giving error "can`t find game object"

Comment: Check this out for your button: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.RepeatButton.html

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by inheriting the event in the button.  Maybe this link could help? http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event.html

Comment: or checking if the button is clicked and then moving it in that direction from player controller, Thanks got the answer from the link

Comment: Use RepeatButton to check if the button is held down, then inside the if block perform direction calculations for player controller.